# Wordpress ACF - How to get field from category page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a website with several categories and now I'm implementing the languages and I need to add a custom field to category page but I can't get the field.

So this is my custom field:
[image]

Next I go to category page and introduce the text in each language.

In my code I do this:

```
<?php
      $obj = get_queried_object();
      $ar = array('child_of' => $obj->term_id);

      $categories = get_categories( $ar );

      foreach($categories as $category) {
        $custom_field = get_field('descricao_traducoes', $obj->term_id);
         var_dump($custom_field);
      }
?>
```

But returns me `null`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just passing the wrong variable as a second parameter in `get_field`!

Do `$category->term_id` instead.

(Unless you meant to dump the `descricao_traducoes` of the queried object for as many times as there are categories)

```
<?php

$obj        = get_queried_object();
$ar         = array('child_of' => $obj->term_id);
$categories = get_categories( $ar );

foreach($categories as $category) {
    $custom_field = get_field('descricao_traducoes', $category->term_id);

    var_dump($custom_field);
}
```

From the [ACF docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/):

> `get_field($selector, [$post_id], [$format_value]);`
>
> - `$selector` *(string) (Required)* The field name or field key.
> - `$post_id` *(mixed) (Optional)* The post ID where the value is saved. Defaults to the current post.
> - `$format_value` *(bool) (Optional)* Whether to apply formatting logic. Defaults to true.

Comment: First off: can you confirm that there's metadata in the database corresponding to that category?